# How can I delete specific files in a folder but not the sub folders?

Tags: powershell

I have a huge folder structure and I want to delete some specific files only from main folders and leave sub folders intact.

Example:

```
Folder A/Sub-folderB/
```

Now , I want to delete files from `Folder A` ONLY , and this should continue until the last folder `N`.

This is the code i have tried ,

```
Get-Childitem C:\serverfolders\users\* | Where-Object {-Not $_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {Remove-Item $_.FullName}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A trailing asterisk in the path parameter turns on recurse. Remove the asterisk and rerun the code

Comment: Your question is unclear, what specific files, in what exact folders? Why do you mix slashes/backslashes? `Get-Childitem "C:\serverfolders\users\*\Folder A\*" -File | Remove-Item -WhatIf` might show what you want to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add "-File" option :)

```
  Get-Childitem C:\serverfolders\users -File | Remove-Item -force
```

You can read more on [Get-ChildItem help on MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-Depth` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` to limit the number of subdirectory levels to include in the recursion. In your case, you only want 1 level deep in order to leave any subfolders intact.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\serverfolders\users' -Depth 1 -File -Recurse | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

You say you *want to delete some specific files only*, and for that you can use the `-Include` parameter of
[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-3.0#parameters) like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\serverfolders\users' -Depth 1 -File -Recurse -Include '*.txt', '*.pdf', '*.doc*' | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

When satisfied with the results on screen, remove the `-WhatIf` switch